# Stuck on my Login Panel

Tags: vb.net

It keeps returning null and I was hoping someone could clean it up for me and see if there is a simpler way to do this. I'm really wanting to start making my game.

```
Public Class frmLogin

Private Sub mnuExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Nick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + Me.txtCUser.Text
    If File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
        Me.lblExists.Text = "Username has already been created!"
        Return
    End If
    If txtCUser.Text.Length < 3 Then
        Me.lblExists.Text = "Must have atleast 3 characters."
        Return
    End If
    Dim writeFile As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\Users\Nick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + Me.txtCUser.Text)
    writeFile.WriteLine("User: " + Me.txtCUser.Text) ' user
    writeFile.WriteLine("Pass: " + Me.txtCPass.Text) ' pass
    writeFile.WriteLine("-------------------")
    writeFile.Close()
End Sub

Private Function GetLine(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal line As Integer) As String
    Try
        If File.Exists(fileName) = False Then
            Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Nick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + Me.txtUser.Text)
                For i As Integer = 1 To line - 1
                    sr.ReadLine()
                Next
                Return (sr.ReadLine())
                sr.Close()
            End Using
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Nick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + Me.txtUser.Text
        If File.Exists(FILE_NAME) And Me.txtPassword.Text = (GetLine(FILE_NAME, 2).Substring(6)) Then
            Me.lblLoggedIn.Text = "Logged"
        ElseIf File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = False Then
            Me.lblLoggedIn.Text = "You must create an account! Navigate to TabPage2."
        End If
End Sub
```

End Class

It would really help a lot. I just started vb not to long ago maybe about a week or two.

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps returning null". What is "it"?

Answer (score 0):

Three things.  First, in GetLine() you're attempting to open the file if it does NOT exist; change from False to True.  Second, you should open the file name that was passed in, not a hard-coded one that uses the value from a TextBox.  Lastly, to get rid of the warning, you need to return something if the file does not exist:

Change GetLine() to:

```
Private Function GetLine(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal line As Integer) As String
    Try
        If File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Using sr As New StreamReader(fileName)
                For i As Integer = 1 To line - 1
                    sr.ReadLine()
                Next
                Return sr.ReadLine()
            End Using
        Else
            Return "{File Not Found: " & fileName & "}"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

*You were returning the exception as a string, so I followed that model with the file not found error.  How will you know, though, if you have an actual error, or if the line in the file was exactly like the "error" being returned?

Comment: Thanks but it is still throwing an error and I'm sorry I wasn't so specific last night I fell asleep right after posting this. Warning Function 'GetLine' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

Comment: If the file didn't exist it was throwing a null because the GetLine didn't return a value. The error just pointed to: Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Nick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + Me.txtUser.Text in btnLogin

Comment: ...and now it returns a value when there is no file.  Did you look at the code and read my comments?  What do YOU want to happen when there is no file?

Comment: I just want it to display that they must make an account. I just ened up adding this Me.lblLoggedIn.Text = "You must create an account! Navigate to TabPage2." Return "{File Not Found: " & fileName & "}"